# MUI Chip: onAdd (Material-UI) equivalent function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I noticed that "onAdd" property is removed from the updated version of Material-UI, MUI. The only property that is a function is "onDelete" and "onClick". I want to create new chips depending on user input tags. Is there any equivalent way of doing so?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I've just come to find out myself that MUI has a component called, "Autocomplete" which is the equivalent of making new chips (and adding tags from user input) with the "ChipInput" component from the older material-UI.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use input fields to trigger the creation of new chips. This [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kofeigen/60urLvod/) (click "Run" to start the demo) has a button that creates chips.

The important code in that demo relating to your question is below under **index.jsx**. The key items are:

1. **createNewChip** function,
2. **chipName** TextField, and
3. **Create New Chip** button.

The *createNewChip* function acts as an event listener for the **onClick** event of the *Create New Chip* button. *createNewChip* takes the text value from the *chipName* TextField and adds it to the **list** variable which is managed by **React.useState**.

**list** is an array of chip data where each element is an object that looks something like this:

```js
{
    id: '11bf5b37-e0b8-42e0-8dcf-dc8c4aefc000',
    value: 'A Wonderful Chip',
    isValid: true
}
```

Hopefully, this helps to get you started on a solution.

### index.jsx

```js
...

export default function ChipMaker() {
    const [ list, setList ] = React.useState( [] );
    const selectedItems = list.filter( ( item ) => item.isValid );
    const selectedLengthIndex = selectedItems.length - 1;

    let listById = {};
    for ( let item of list ) {
        listById[ item.id ] = item;
    }

    ...

    function createNewChip() {
        let chipName = document.getElementById( 'chipName' ).value;
        let newList = list.concat( {
            id: uuidv4(),
            value: chipName,
            isValid: true
        } );

        setList( newList );
    }

    ...

    return (
        <Stack spacing={3} sx={{ width: 500 }}>
            <Autocomplete
                multiple
                id="tags-filled"
                filterSelectedOptions={ true }
                options={ list.map(( item ) => item.id) }
                value={ list.map(( item ) => item.id) }
                freeSolo
                renderTags={( listIds, getTagProps) =>
                    listIds.map(( id, index) => (
                        <Chip
                            key={ index }
                            variant="outlined"
                            label={ listById[ id ].value }
                            sx={ {
                                color: ( theme ) => {
                                    let chipColor = '#fff';
                                    if ( typeof( listById[ id ] ) == 'object' ) {
                                        chipColor = listById[ id ].isValid
                                            ? theme.palette.common.white 
                                            : theme.palette.common.white
                                    }
                                    return chipColor;
                                },

                                backgroundColor: ( theme ) => {
                                    let chipColor = '#fff';
                                    if ( typeof( listById[ id ] ) == 'object' ) {
                                        chipColor = listById[ id ].isValid
                                            ? theme.palette.primary.main 
                                            : theme.palette.error.main
                                    }
                                    return chipColor;
                                },
                            
                                [`& .MuiSvgIcon-root.MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium.MuiChip-deleteIcon.MuiChip-deleteIconMedium.MuiChip-deleteIconColorDefault.MuiChip-deleteIconOutlinedColorDefault`]: {
                                    fill: ( theme ) => theme.palette.grey[200]                
                                }
                            } }
                            {...getTagProps({ index })}
                        />
                    ))
                }
                renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField
                        {...params}
                        variant="filled"
                        label="Material-UI Chip Input Test"
                        placeholder="Favorites"
                    />
                )}
                onChange={ validateInput }
            />

            <div>
                { selectedItems.map( ( item, index ) => {
                    let comma = null;
                    if ( selectedLengthIndex != index ) {
                        comma = (<span key={ 'idx'+index }>, </span>);
                    }

                    return (
                        item.isValid
                            ? <span key={ index }>{ item.value }{ comma }</span>
                            : null
                    );
                } ) }
            </div>

            <TextField
                id='chipName'
                name='chipName'
                className={ 'test' }
                type='text'
                label={ 'Chip name' }
                fullWidth={ false }
                variant='standard'
                inputProps={ { maxLength: 20 } }
                helperText={ 'Enter chip name' }
                InputLabelProps={ {
                    'variant': 'standard',
                    'color': 'primary',
                    'disableAnimation': false
                } }
                FormHelperTextProps={ { 'variant': 'standard' } }
                error={ false }
                defaultValue={ '' }
                placeholder={ 'New chip name' }
                color={ 'info' }
            />

            <Button
                variant={ 'contained' }
                onClick={ createNewChip }
                sx={ {
                    width: '200px'    
                } }
            >
                { 'Create new chip' }
            </Button>
        </Stack>
    );
}


/**
 * Inject component into DOM
 */
root.render(
    <ChipMaker />
);
```

Comment: I don't know if my comment got deleted or not but thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad you found a solution.